# How To Make This Border Example

Tags: html

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="Border.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<title>Border</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td rowspan="2">Today's Opinion Poll Question</td>
<td colspan="3">Political party</td>
</tr>
<td>Democrat</td>
<td>Republican</td>
<td>Independent</td>
<tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="3">Do you favor or oppose increasing the minimum wage?"</td>
<td>Favor</td>
<td>70%</td>
<td>35%</td>
<td>55%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Oppose</td>
<td>25%</td>
<td>60%</td>
<td>30%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Unsure</td>
<td>5%</td>
<td>5%</td>
<td>15%</td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to make a table that looks exactly like the photo I posted, but I'm having a hard time to get it right and I dont know why. Can someone please explain to me how you make this border in detail? I have a hard time putting Favor, Oppose, and Unsure correctly can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you. [border example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su4MW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that seems to be missing is expanding the "Today's Opinion Poll Question" over 2 columns. Add colspan="2" attribute to that cell ie:

```
<td rowspan="2" colspan="2">Today's Opinion Poll Question</td>
```